# Edit Validation Errors in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a registration form on my website. Im having trouble editing the errors when the registration form is filled out incorrectly. I have done this code in my forms.py but it also displays djangos regular validation error.

```py
class lageBruker(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password1',
                  'password2']

    def clean_brukernavn(self):
        brukernavn = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

        bruker_qs = User.objects.filter(username = brukernavn)
        if bruker_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Brukernavn allerede i bruk')
        return brukernavn

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        passord1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        passord2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if passord1 != passord2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passordene må være like')
        return super(lageBruker, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

I there any way i can edit the validation error that django is throwing?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment due to low rep, can you provide an exact error message that you would like to replace? for passwords for example there's `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` pipeline inside your settings.py that you can replace or remove.

Comment: i just want to translate the text from english to norwegian for all the fields. Can i do this in setting.py?